# BLE [connectedPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:aChar];

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am pretty sure I know the answer to this, been searching all around. I have a CSR board providing a GATT server. I am connecting to it and have the ability to write to it and do a read request. However , one of the CSR developers is looking for me to attach a payload to the ... read request.

```
[connectedPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:aChar];
```

From what I know about BLE there are only two ways to do a read request, like this,

```
[connectedPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:(nonnull CBCharacteristic *)];
[connectedPeripheral readValueForDescriptor:(nonnull CBDescriptor *)];
```

They want me to attach a payload that looks like this to it. But I believe it is impossible, Help if you can...
Thanks
JZ

```
const char myByteArray [] = {

       0xA1,0x07,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0xCF
    };
```

Regards

JZ

Comment: That would be a write, not a read. If a device needs input data that it is going to respond to, you would typically issue a write to the peripheral and then the peripheral would issue a `notify` with the response when it was ready

Comment: Paul, thanks , this is what I thought , but some colleague thought differently. Thanks much.